# Angular promise: intercept "then"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Right now I have an Angular service named `chartModelService` with this method on it:

```
this.fetchChartModel = function() {
    return $http.get(fullUrlPath);
};
```

And I have an Angular controller that consumes this data:

```
chartModelService.fetchChartModel().then(function(rawData) {
    var chartData = chartModelService.translate(rawData);
    $scope.populateChart(chartData);
});
```

I would like to perform the `chartModelService.translate(data)` within the `chartModelService` instead of the controller using the service. In other words, I would like to change to controller to the code below, where the `chartData` it receives has already been translated:

```
chartModelService.fetchChartModel().then(function(chartData) {
    $scope.populateChart(chartData);
});
```

How can I change `chartModelService.fetchChartModel()` so that it performs `translate()` before returning the promised data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
this.fetchChartModel = function() {
    return $http.get(fullUrlPath);
};
```

To This:

```
this.fetchChartModel = function() {
    var defObj = $q.defer();

    var fetch = $http.get(fullUrlPath);
    fetch.then(function(data){
        defObj.resolve(chartModelService.translate(data));
    });

    return defObj.promise;
};
```

(with the appropriate DI on your service, of course)

This will init the data fetch and return a promise that contains your translated data when it has been fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

just move your code ;)

```
this.fetchChartModel = function() {
    return $http.get(fullUrlPath)
    .then(function(rawData) {
        return $q.resolve(chartModelService.translate(rawData);)
    });
};
```

that should do it just make sure you include $q service in your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

For me didn't work $q.resolve, but you can use instead $q.when

```
this.fetchChartModel = function() {
    return $http.get(fullUrlPath)
    .then(function(rawData) {
        return $q.when(chartModelService.translate(rawData));
    });
};
```